# How can I use a changing int value to call different functions on an Arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am programming (kind of) a stopwatch with start buttons and a 4-digit seven-segment LED display on my Arduino Uno.

With functions like this one I can put numbers on the SevSeg without problems:

```
void Zahl_1()
{
  digitalWrite(6, LOW);
  digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(8, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(9, LOW);
  digitalWrite(10, LOW);
  digitalWrite(11, LOW);
  digitalWrite(12, LOW);
}
```

By clicking a button a can start the clock (numbers are stored in `int sekunden`) and Serialprint does give me the right numbers counting up.

My problem lies in between both; I cant link for example `(sekunden == 1)` to `Zahl_1()`.

I tried it this way with no success:

```cpp
void Sek()
{
  if (sekunden == 0)
  {
    Zahl_0;  //
  }
  if (sekunden == 1)
  {
    Zahl_1;
  }
  if (sekunden == 2)
  {
    Zahl_2;
  }
  if (sekunden == 3)
  {
    Zahl_3;
  }
  if (sekunden == 4)
  {
    Zahl_4;
  }
  if (sekunden == 5)
  {
    Zahl_5;
  }
  if (sekunden == 6)
  {
    Zahl_6;
  }
  if (sekunden == 7)
  {
    Zahl_7;
  }
  if (sekunden == 8)
  {
    Zahl_8;
  }
  if (sekunden == 9)
  {
    Zahl_9;
  }
}
```

Any ideas on how to get this working without having to rewrite the whole program?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards

bamm

Comment: You forgot the (); call the function Zahl_1 by writing `Zahl_1();`. You may also want to write one function `void Zahl(int number)` that can handle all numbers instead of having a separate function for each number.

Comment: Oh, facepalm all the way. Thanks a lot!
It,s my first time programming in C++, i will never forget to write () behind function-calls again.
And thanks for the hint for the function, i will implement that right away.

Comment: you shouldn't mix German and English in your code. use English names.  at least You know that this is C++, now you know more than 99% of all people asking Arduino questions :)

Comment: @Piglet Thanks for the hint, i'll keep that in mind and stick to English terms!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you're not calling any function. To call a function you do:

```
function();
```

In your example you are missing the parentheses.

Another thing I want to point out is your use of if statements. It's more efficient and a better practice to use switch statements when doing stuff depending on the value of a variable.

Example:

```
switch (sekunden) {
  case 0:
    Zahl_0();
    break;
  case 1:
    Zahl_1();
    break;
  case 2:
    Zahl_2();
    break;
  default:
    println("Nothing matches");
    break;
}
```

More info here: [Switch case structure](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/structure/control-structure/switchcase/)

Comment: Thank you for the advice and the example. Much appreciated!